# How to Get GVim which can be Killed by CTRL-W?

Tags: gvim, neovim

I am trying to view many files in a loop. I need a keybinding to close Gvim window. Possible choices in apt-get of Ubuntu 16.04

```
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk3' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gnome' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-athena' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-nox-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-nox' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk3-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gnome-py2' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-tiny' (main)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-gtk' (universe)
 Command 'gvim' from package 'vim-athena-py2' (universe)
```

I have tried

- vim-gtk3, no CTRL-W to close the window

I would like to get Neovim with such a feature.

---

Is there any GVim with window-closure by CTRL-W?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a map in your vimrc to give <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> the action you are looking for.

```
:nnoreamp <C-W> :q<cr>
```

If you want it to force quit then

```
:nnoremap <C-W> :q!<cr>
```

Comment: If you do that, though, you will lose access to the rich set of windows commands that begin with Ctrl-W. See `:help CTRL-W` and `:help windows`.

Comment: Is there any other suggestion for such a closure command? I noticed that <C-W> is bad. For Linux support.

Comment: In normal mode pressing ZZ will "Save and Quit" while ZQ will quit without saving. Both are very quick, no need for a chord to press.